# ModelForm not processing upload

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, amazon-s3

I have a ModelForm in django:

```py
class uploadform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = upload
        fields = ['email', 'title', 'date', 'file']
```

From the model:

```
class upload(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateField()
    file = models.FileField()
```

Here is my view for processing the form:

```py
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = uploadform(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('upload')

    else:
        form = uploadform()

    context = {
        'form': form
    }

    return render(request, 'content/upload.html', context)
```

Here is my HTML:

```html
<div class="site-section mb-5">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="form-register">
     <form method="POST">
         {% csrf_token %}
             <legend>Upload Content</legend>
             <div class="form-group">
               {{ form | crispy }}
            </div>
             <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Upload</button>
     </form>
```

Form populates well, form will allow me to attach, but whenever I press "Upload", I get redirected without the file actually going to S3 or the form being saved in the database. I know my S3 connection is correct because If I go to `admin` and create an upload, the file will appear in S3.

What could be causing the file upload from the `form.save()` to not work?

Comment: Your form should have as `enctype` `multipart/form-data`, so `<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">`.

Comment: Can you describe problem more precisely. What do you mean by "redirected with the file actually going to S3" and what you want to achieve after clicking "Upload"?

Comment: Edited for typo. *without file going to S3

Comment: Please start your class names with a capital. That way, there's easier to distinguish between classes and variables/functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Willem in comment above:

"Your form should have as `enctype` `multipart/form-data`, so `<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">` "